# Concatenation of many lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
def getNeighbors(vertex)
```

which returns a list of vertices that are neighbors of the given vertex. Now I want to create a list with all the neighbors of the neighbors. I do that like this:

```
listOfNeighborsNeighbors = []
for neighborVertex in getNeighbors(vertex):
    listOfNeighborsNeighbors.append(getNeighbors(neighborsVertex))
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do that?

Comment: I think both the duplicate and this question choose the wrong answer, though. [See here for the more pythonic/performant answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/365102)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
[x for n in getNeighbors(vertex) for x in getNeighbors(n)]
```

or

```
sum(getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex), [])
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest a list comprehension. IMHO, it's the most pythonic way.

Comment: However, see the timing comparisons, as comments under emu's answer: both "itertools.chain" and "reduce(iadd" are more than twice as fast as the nested list comprehension -- and MUCH faster than sum(), which degrades rapidly with # elements processed.

Comment: So glad I found this. Tried many times, never with such a 2nd argument `[]` to the sum of lists.

Comment: Second solution looks very cool. And works in practice. And it cost me hours of profiling and debugging because it just doesn't work for large N! Please put a note that the second solution has quadratic time complexity!

Answer (score 78):

As usual, the itertools module contains a solution:

```
>>> l1=[1, 2, 3]

>>> l2=[4, 5, 6]

>>> l3=[7, 8, 9]

>>> import itertools

>>> list(itertools.chain(l1, l2, l3))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Therefore the solution to the question is `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex)))`

Comment: If `ls = [l1,l2,l3]` use `list(itertools.chain(*ls))`.

Answer (score 45):

Appending lists can be done with + and sum():

```
>>> c = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> sum(c, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks - I *knew* there had to be some way to do this with sum! BTW, it wasn't clear to me that this would work with more than 2 sub-lists, or variable length lists; so clearer example might be: `c = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]` => `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: BUT see the timings I did as comments under emu's answer. **DO NOT USE SUM -- VERY SLOW** FOR 100 lists of 100 items!

Comment: Why is the second argument to sum required? I would think sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) was clear as day to mean [1, 2] + [3, 4].

Comment: @KeithWM Because `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` does not mean `[1, 2] + [3, 4]`, but rather `0 + [1, 2] + [3, 4]`, which doesn't work. You need the optional second argument to replace that starting `0` with a `[]`, so that `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [])` is `[] + [1, 2] + [3, 4]`.

Comment: @Stef Thank you very much! That explains a lot of errors I've experienced in the past while using sum.

Answer (score 16):

Quickest to slowest:

```
list_of_lists = [[x,1] for x in xrange(1000)]

%timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
30 µs ± 320 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit list(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
33.4 µs ± 761 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

min(timeit.repeat("ll=[];\nfor l in list_of_lists:\n ll.extend(l)", "list_of_lists=[[x,1] for x in range(1000)]",repeat=3, number=100))/100.0
4.1411130223423245e-05

%timeit [y for z in list_of_lists for y in z]
53.9 µs ± 156 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit sum(list_of_lists, [])
1.5 ms ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

(Python 3.7.10)

Python2:

```
list_of_lists = [[x,1] for x in xrange(1000)]

%timeit list(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop

%timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 µs per loop

min(timeit.repeat("ll=[];\nfor l in list_of_lists:\n ll.extend(l)", "list_of_lists=[[x,1] for x in xrange(1000)]",repeat=3, number=100))/100.0
9.620904922485351e-05

%timeit [y for z in list_of_lists for y in z]
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop

%timeit sum(list_of_lists, [])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: `itertools.chain(list_of_lists)` is wrong (it won't concatenate anything because it's only given one parameter). You need a `*` there, or `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: These timing results might be obsolete.
Testing on 2018 HW with python3.6.6, I don't see any reproducible speed difference between the itertools.chain, itertools.chain.from_iterable, and functools.reduce/iadd solutions. YMMV.
The iadd solution changes the inputs, though.

Comment: nobody said anything about the list of lists being dynamic so the from_iterable solution is off-topic imo

Answer (score 13):

If speed matters, it may be better to use this:

```
from operator import iadd
reduce(iadd, (getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex)))
```

The point of this code is in concatenating whole lists by `list.extend` where list comprehension would add one item by one, as if calling `list.append`. That saves a bit of overhead, making the former (according to my measurements) about three times faster. (The `iadd` operator is normally written as `+=` and does the same thing as `list.extend`.)

Using list comprehensions (the first solution by Ignacio) is still usually the right way, it is easier to read.

But definitely avoid using `sum(..., [])`, because it runs in quadratic time. That is very impractical for *many* lists (more than a hundred or so).

Comment: Thanks for the comment re sum's performance -- I liked how compact that code is, so good to know not to use it on large scale. IMHO, Jochen's itertools'chain solution from '10 is a more appropriate solution than reduce: it more directly/simply does what is being asked for.

Comment: I take back what I said about chain being more appropriate. While I do find it easier to read/understand, it has a slight performance issue, if the ultimate goal is to make a list: it passes back elements one at a time, so the list cannot predict how long it will be. In that sense, it is more similar to list comprehension/append than to reduce/extend. With timeit, for 100 lists x 100 elements each, reduce/iadd vs chain roughly equal time (1.1). With 4x the data (200 lists x 200 elements each), reduce wins (2.6 vs 4.0).

Comment: WARNING: iadd MODIFIES the first list passed in. Doesn't matter in the example, because the lists are results from a function. But I did one test where I passed in a list of lists that I had pre-computed. Altered my original list, which was not good to do. FIX: instead of `reduce(iadd, LL)` or even `reduce(iadd, (L for L in LL))`, must wrap each returned L in list(): `reduce(iadd, (list(L) for L in LL))`. This forces each L to be copied. (Which is quick, because size is known.).

Comment: .. List comprehension degrades more quickly (2.4 => 9.1). Sum is WAY worse (13.8 => 130.2)! Repeating those numbers together for easier comparison: (reduce, chain, comprehension, sum) @ 100x100 = (1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 13.8); @ 200x200 = (2.6, 4.0, 9.1, 130.2).

Comment: Test code (python 2.7): `print timeit('all = reduce(operator.iadd, (list(list_) for list_ in LL))', number=1000, setup='n = 100;  import operator;  L1 = list(range(n));  LL = [[10 * x + v for v in L1] for x in range(n)]')`
 `print timeit('all = list(itertools.chain(*LL))', number=1000, setup='n = 100;  L1 = list(range(n));  LL = [[10 * x + v for v in L1] for x in range(n)]')`
 `print timeit('all = [x for list_ in LL for x in list_]', number=...` `print timeit('all = sum(LL, [])', number=...` THEN repeat those 4, with `n = 200;` instead of `100`. (Then I multiplied the resulting times by 10)

Comment: @emu do you know why sum runs in quadratic time? That surprises me.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you can add a second argument to `reduce` as an initial value, circumventing the need to copy the lists.

Comment: @drevicko Because it has no choice but to construct a new list during each addition, and that is a linear-time operation.

Answer (score 3):

I like `itertools.chain` approach because it runs in linear time (sum(...) runs in qudratic time) but @Jochen didn't show how to deal with lists of dynamic length. Here is solution for OP's question.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*[getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex)]))
```

You can get rid of `list(...)` call if iterable is sufficient for you.

Comment: You can also get rid of the unpacking `*[getNeighbors...]` by using `chain.from_iterable` like this: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex)))`

Comment: Or you can keep the unpacking but not have it generate a list by doing `list(itertools.chain(*(getNeighbors(n) for n in getNeighbors(vertex))))`

Answer (score 0):

Using **.extend()** (update in place) combined with reduce instead of **sum()** (new object each time) should be more efficient however I'm too lazy to test that :)

```
mylist = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] 
reduce(lambda acc_l, sl: acc_l.extend(sl) or acc_l, mylist)
```

Comment: It is indeed faster, but as [Yariv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277438/160206)  shows, it's not the fastest approach.