# Possible to append multiple lists at once? (Python)

Tags: python, list, append

I have a bunch of lists I want to append to a single list that is sort of the "main" list in a program I'm trying to write. Is there a way to do this in one line of code rather than like 10? I'm a beginner so I have no idea...

For a better picture of my question, what if I had these lists:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [7, 8, 9]
```

And want to append y and z to x. Instead of doing:

```
x.append(y)
x.append(z)
```

Is there a way to do this in one line of code? I already tried:

```
x.append(y, z)
```

And it wont work.

Comment: Do you really want `.append`, or `.extend`? Do you understand the difference?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: No, I have never seen .extend before, what does it do?

Comment: What do you think about itertools.[chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) ?

Comment: `.append` will add an element to the list. `.extend` will concatenate a list to a list.

Comment: Yeah. Tried one of the answers here. Was making lists of lists, but instead it put all the elements of the lists into one list. Sticking with 8 appends.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
x.extend(y+z)
```

should do what you want

or

```
x += y+z
```

or even

```
x = x+y+z
```

Comment: Note the last one is subtly different - you are creating a new list and assigning it to `x`, as opposed to changing `x` in place.

Comment: I tried .extend and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the extend method keeps returning None for me.

Comment: `extend` and `append` methods return `None`, they modify the list in-place.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `sum` function with start value (empty list) indicated:

```
a = sum([x, y, z], [])
```

This is especially more suitable if you want to append an arbitrary number of lists.

Answer (score 20):

Extending my comment

```
In [1]: x = [1, 2, 3]
In [2]: y = [4, 5, 6]
In [3]: z = [7, 8, 9]
In [4]: from itertools import chain
In [5]: print list(chain(x,y,z))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Simple form of the itertools option which I found useful: `itertools.chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])` = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 3):

To exactly replicate the effect of append, try the following function, simple and effective:

```
a=[]
def concats (lists):
    for i in lists:
        a==a.append(i)


concats ([x,y,z])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a slightly more functional approach, you could try:

```
import functools as f

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [7, 8, 9]

x = f.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [y, z], x)
```

This will enable you to concatenate any number of lists onto list `x`.

If you would just like to concatenate any number of lists together (i.e. not onto some base list), you can simplify to:

```
import functools as f
from operator import add
big_list = f.reduce(add, list_of_lists)
```

Take note that our BFDL has his reservations with regard to lambdas, reduce, and friends: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

To complete this answer, you can read more about reduce in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

I quote: "Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value."

P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277438/532513 compares the performance of different approaches for list concatenation.

Comment: Please edit/fix the following: "it does seem to work with lists, and is really fast". The linked answer shows the opposite actually, at 1.5 ms it is the, by far, slowest solution.

Comment: I think that might be due to Py 3.7 not being out yet when I wrote that answer. Anyawys, thanks for heads-up, I'll update answer.

Answer (score 1):

equivalent to above answer, but sufficiently different to be worth a mention:

```
my_map = {
   'foo': ['a', 1, 2],
   'bar': ['b', '2', 'c'],
   'baz': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
} 
list(itertools.chain(*my_map.values()))
['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 1, 2, 'b', '2', 'c']
```

in the above expression, * is important for groking result as args to chain, this is same as prior chain(x,y,z). Also, note the result is hash-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

In one line , it can be done in following ways

```
x.extend(y+z)
```

or

```
x=x+y+z
```