# How to Insert multiple element lists into a SQL table into separate rows

Tags: python, sql

I have a list of strings:

```
setdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME")
for s in setdata:
   searchid = s.Id
   summary = s.Summary
```

Output

```
   ['abuse', 'accuse', 'axis', 'decrease']
   ['crime', 'frodge']
```

I have to Insert the above output into another SQL table as:

```
sid  searchid     keywords
-----------------------------
1      122        abuse
2      122        accuse
3      122        axis
4      122        decrease
5      123        crime
6      123        frodge
```

How can I insert the data in this way?

Comment: Concatenate all the lists, then use `executemany()` to insert them all.

Comment: @Barmar  Multiple lists are being generated from the loop, How do we concatenate them for get into one .

Comment: `full_list = sum(list_of_lists, [])`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021641/concatenation-of-many-lists-in-python for all the different ways to combine lists into one big list.

Comment: @Barmar -Thanks for the response , -  We can't do like the same as have to insert the List according to the separate text row ID inside a loop.

Comment: @Neeraj The `sid` column should ideally be auto increment; you don't set that value, your database does.