# Join starred expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Probably I have not yet fully understood what starred expression means in python, but I'm having some troubles with this part.

I have some working code that allows me to run multiple async functions in parallel, each feeding a different parameter to a function, by writing this:

```
result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather( *( func1(c) for c in mylist ) ))
```

Now I need to call two functions in a similar way, and merge the two results. One thing I can do is

```
result1 = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather( *( func1(c) for c in mylist ) ))
result2 = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather( *( func2(c) for c in mylist ) ))
result = result1 + result2
```

The parameters are the same for both `func1` and `func2`.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to just call it once, something like

```
result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather( *( func1(c), func2(c) for c in mylist ) ))
```

(which of course does not work). `result`'s order is not important (I can have all `func1` results and then all `func2` results or have `func1(c0), func2(c0), func1(c1), func2(c1), ...`).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
( func1(c) for c in mylist )
```

You create a generator

When you wrote

```
*( func1(c) for c in mylist )
```

You are getting all the elements from your generator. The same would happen in a list, for instance if you have

```
[func(c1), func(c2), func(c3)]
```

Then using unpacking you will have

```
func(c1) func(c2) func(c3)
```

The problem in your case is that `*( func1(c), func2(c) for c in mylist ) )` is creating something like `(func1(c1), func2(c1)) (func1(c2), func2(c2))` and so on. You are creating tuples, not isolated elements

Thus you need to remove the tuple part. A solution would be to concatenate everything and then unpack.

```
result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather( *sum(([func1(c), func2(c)] for c in mylist), []) ))
```

Where I used sum( tuple of lists, []) to [concatenate all lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3021662/9964778) before the unpack